# KiCAD - Symbol for power connector

Tags: arduino, power, connector, kicad, symbol

I am trying to create what is to be my first pcb, and also my first arduino shield.

The circuit requires the power connector (power jack) that the arduino has.

I am sure i can find that footprint inside KiCAD.
But what do i select for schematic symbol?

Comment: Can you put the connector part number in your question.  That would make it much easier to construct detailed answers.

Comment: @user4574 Hmmm i don't know the connector part number, and neither do i know where to find this infomation.

Comment: If you tell me which Arduino board model you are plugging into then you or myself can look up the mating part numbers from its schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR THE SYMBOL:**
The symbol for a connector is typically just a rectangle with a line of pins on it.  The specifics of the symbol don't really matter.  The only thing that matters is that you have the right number of pins on it and that the pin names on the symbol match the pin names in the footprint.

a)  You can use the KI-CAD symbol editor to make the connector symbol.
b)  You can look for any other connector symbol that has the same number of pins and use that.

**FOR THE FOOTPRINT:**
a)  You can see if one is in the library.
b)  If you have the part number for the connector you can get a datasheet for it.  Using the datasheet you can use the KI-CAD footprint editor to make what you need.  Making a footprint usually only takes a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Since KiCAD doesn't care: any connector symbol with the same number of pins will do. Make sure that the numbering stays the same.